# what's the difference between object complement and "that" clause?

Tags: meaning, complements

I'm not a native English speaker.

for me, those two sentences are the same meaning:

one): it was more about me being obsessed with the job.

two): it was more about that I was obsessed with the job.

Comment: Yes, the same meaning, but the second one is ungrammatical because the preposition "about" does not license (permit) a _that_- clause as complement. Note that you can say "It was more about the fact that I was obsessed with the job".

Comment: @BillJ Are you familiar with OP's use of 'object complement' in the title? I've only seen this as a designation for predicate complements which characterize a direct object.

Comment: @StoneyB Odd, isn't it? Since the OP was asking about meaning, I skipped over the wording of the title. There's no transitive verb/direct object, so no object complement of course. Btw, would you not consider "obsessed" to be an adjective (not a verb), so "obsessed with the job" is an AdjP as PC of "being". Adjectival "obsessed" does select the prep "with" so it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @BillJ  Yes, on reconsideration you're right -- the comment clause is a copulation, not a passive. I'll amend my answer accordingly

Comment: Not to disagree with BillJ's remark that "*about* does not license a *that*-clause". To my ear, it does not. But I've been hearing this construction with increasing frequency from speakers who are in their twenties, who use "It was more about..." as if it were a variant of  "The real reason was" and give it the licensing that phrase has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both your sentences the subordinate clause headed by *BE* is the object (or 'oblique') of the preposition *about*.

Terminology varies widely, but I'm only familiar with 'object complement' as a designation for a 'predicate' or 'predicative' complement of a verb which characterizes the verb's direct object:

> The dean named Prof. Sartorius **chair of the committee**.
>   We painted the room **red**.
>   Please put it **on the shelf**.

Your number 'two' is at best only marginally grammatical in contemporary English. There are only a few prepositions which license full finite clauses ('content' clauses) introduced by *that* as their objects; Huddleston and Pullum, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, 2002, p.971 lists these:

*`but       considering         except     given         granted`

       `in        notwithstanding     now        provided      providing`

       `save      seeing              so         supposing`*

*That* cannot be omitted with *in* or with *but* in the sense 'except', and with *so* the use with *that* may have a different meaning than the use without it. *That* can be omitted with the others (but the omission with *notwithstanding* and *save* has a very old-fashioned ring).

These prepositions may take content clauses as their objects, but *that* must be omitted:

*`after       although     as        as if       as long as     as soon as`

       `because     before       for       for all     if             in case`

       `lest        like         once      since       though         till/until`

       `unless      when         where     whereas`*

*CGEL* also lists (p.623) a handful of 'prepositional expressions' which may be followed by *that* clauses: the *that* may be omitted with *`in the event`*, *`on the grounds`*, *`for all`*, *`for fear`*, and *`on condition`* but must be included with *`in order`*.

With any other preposition I'd advise you to stick to the gerund (*-ing* form) clause used in your number 'one'.

Comment: A fine answer! But just want to ask you if **about my being obsessed** and **about me being obsessed** is the same. Agree that **my being obsessed** is an oblique, but **me being obsessed**? I don't think it is. I think **me** is the object of **about**, and **being obsessed** is a Gerund-participle, here modifying the object of the preposition.

Comment: @Man_From_India That's the traditional analysis; but that traditional analysis led to the rational but unhappily counterfactual notion that the *-ing* form which heads these chunks is a kind of noun, which requires that the subject be cast in possessive case, ***my** being obsessed*, so you end up with a 'legitimate' noun **phrase**. Contemporary analysis says that what's going on here is the 'object' of the preposition is not a phrase but a **clause**--the state expressed by *I BE obsessed*, and the pronoun *I* picks up the accusative case by a process that sort of ...

Comment: 'compromises' by putting case on the only element in the clause that can take case, the pronoun. Certainly "it" isn't about ***me***; it's about the fact that "I am obsessed..."

Comment: thank you. It's now clear. I always get confused in such things.